# Can HTML popups, and other parts of the page not relevant to the user's query hamper SEO?

Tags: seo, google, pagination, infinite-scroll

We have e-commerce mobile website where most of our traffic comes through SEO.

Currently, when user types: "buy Samsung phones", Google ranks our website i.e. `https://www.example.com/samsung-phones/`

This page has infinite scroll and shows multiple Samsung phones. On page load, we fetch only top 20. Rest of the phone comes as the user scrolls down.

Each of 20 listing has Samsung keyword in it. But I noticed that we are fetching too much extra HTML on page load here i.e. HTML for pop-up that comes on users first visit to get users email id, HTML for filters, sort etc. All these i.e. pop up for email, sort and filter section has nothing to do with users Google query i.e. "buy Samsung phones". Would Google penalize our ranking due to these irrelevant HTML blocks we have on the page?

Does having maximum of Samsung phone links, text, information on that page and removing all other information boost our SEO rank?

Comment: Almost all sites have some parts of the page like header, navigation, and footer that are not directly related to what the user searched for.   As long as the user can spot the content they searched for right away, you should be fine.   The only worrying part for me is that you mentioned popups.   Those can hurt SEO.

Answer (score 3):

> ...Each of 20 listings has Samsung keyword in it.

That can be a problem especially when you don't talk about the phones with sufficient detail.

Having paragraphs like this is terrible (excuse me if I can't name the phones right).

```
Samsung galaxy 1

This samsung phone named the galaxy is a wonderful samsung product 
made by Samsung america and Samsung China with precious material 
from Samsung Canada with assistance from Samsung thailand.

Samsung blackbox v2

This samsung phone has all features you need from samsung. 
It has samsung premiere app, samsung exotic music, and comes 
with samsung total care package from samsung japan. Extra support 
available from samsung united states. Speak to a samsung rep for details.
```

Notice how many times I used Samsung? Thats basically keyword stuffing. 
What you want to do is make natural paragraphs people want to read and if you can get at least a couple paragraphs on each phone, then you can have one separate whole webpage for each phone.

If you want category pages, then consider using the manufacturer only once then use the names of phones for the names people can select.

the following menu style is bad (ignore creative spelling errors):

```
Select a phone:

    Samsung Galaxy
    Samsung Black Box
    Samsung Premiumness
    Samsung JukeSter
    Samsung PinkyPinks
    Samsung Girl Specials
    Microsoft ThinFlop
    Microsoft SleekPad
    Microsoft UltraSlick
```

Instead, consider this kind of menu:

```
We have the following phones. Select one from the appropriate    
manufacturer:

    Samsung:

    Galaxy
    Black Box
    Premiumness
    JukeSter
    PinkyPinks
    Girl Specials

    Microsoft:

    ThinFlop
    SleekPad
    UltraSlick
```

> All these i.e. pop up for email, sort and filter section has nothing to do with users google query i.e. "buy Samsung phones". Would google penalize our ranking due to these irrelevant html blocks?
>
> ... HTML for pop-up that comes on users first visit ...

This is terrible. The last thing a user wants to see is a page nicely loaded only to find out while reading a paragraph that a pop-up suddenly appears on the screen. That alone is a bad user experience. You're much better off to have an option in the page itself with a simple link to allow the user to subscribe (or to the email). If you must use pop-ups then make them only appear AFTER the user expresses consent by clicking on the appropriate link. For example, add some button on your site labeled "subscribe" and when the user clicks on it, then you can make a pop-up window with the relevant form.